# Refering the %USERPROFILE% environment variable failed

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I create a new environment variable in the environment variable settings GUI tool in Windows
Name: ATOM_HOME
Value: %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\atom-windows\Atom

When I echo %USERPROFILE% in a new cmd window
`echo %ATOM_HOME%`
it return `%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\atom-windows\Atom` which doesn't expand the %USERPROFILE% variale.

If I echo %TMP% which is predefined as  `TMP=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` , I get 
`C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp` which does expand the %USERPROFILE% variale.

How do I reference %USERPROFILE% in a new environment variable?

Comment: Possible ordering problem in the environment list setup? Problem with system/user variable distinction?

Comment: If you're in a domain, you can configure a user environment variable for all users using group policy preferences.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to set the value as a **user** variable, not a **system** variable.

Comment: (Because system variables can't reference user variables.)

Answer (score 1):

**Open command prompt and run the following command:**

```
setx ATOM_HOME %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\atom-windows\Atom
```

If you place `/m` on the end of the above command it specifies to set the variable in the system environment. The default setting is the local environment.

Reboot your computer.

To debug and see the environment variable values then you can make a list of the current environment variables by running the following command from the command line which will save the environment variables values to a file:

`set > C:\env_list.txt`

The file name "C:\env_list.txt" can be replaced by any of your choice.

[Technet Microsoft- using setx examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx)

Comment: You're unlike to want `/m` in this case.  That would set everybody's `ATOM_HOME` to point into a single user's profile.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - true but there may be a reason to have all accounts reference the value that was set when the variable was created with the user logged in but for the most part you are right and there would properly be a better approach.